# How to setup variable to point to global object – independent of context execution?

Tags: javascript, module

Can someone please explain to me what the heck does this mean?

```
!function (global, moduleDefinition) {
  'use strict';

  var dependencies = [];

  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define(dependencies, moduleDefinition);
  } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    module.exports = moduleDefinition.apply(null, dependencies);
  } else {
    global.Utilities = moduleDefinition.apply(null, dependencies);
  }

}(this, function () {
  'use strict';

  var Utilities = {};

  return Utilities;

});
```

This has been passed to me to follow as our new module.

Joe

Comment: @Quentin where in this question is mentioned about exclamation mark?

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski — Very first character of code in the question. (Otherwise it is a "Close as unclear what you are asking" or "Too broad" because there are lots of different things that could be explained in that question. It really should have been written to have been more clearly focused in the first place).

Comment: @Quentin – the title of question was changes – how about now?

Comment: Sounds better, thanks.

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski — It would be better if the OP clarified what they meant rather than people answering it putting their interpretation there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- ! exclamation mark (or any other symbol lie (+) turns code to expression - you can invoke it immediately

### Example

```
(function() {}());
!function() {}();
```

### Wrong version

You can’t invoke function declaration!

```
function() {}() // wrong, don’t try to run this
```

### Example

You can pass arguments to invoked function

```
(function(foo) {
    console.log(foo, foo === 3); //3, true foo is equal to passed value
}(3));
```

You can pass global object – in browser environment it this points to **window object**, in Node – it points to **global object**. As we want write one version of code without forking it for environment detection it is simpler to use global as variable that can hold pointer to global object. Compare `window.setTimeout` (for browser) vs `this.setTimeout` (for Node) vs `global.setTimeout` (for both)

```
(function(global) {
    global.setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('I’m running independent to browser or server environment');
    }, 1000);
}(this));
```

You have missed something for moduleDefinition, where is rest?

Comment: This is great I got it now, one thing more, why do we pass global variables to the invoked function if the function already has access to them? what is the point of that?

Comment: This simple function has acccess to **global this**, but it can be executed as method of some object. After that – `this` will points to the object itself instead of global.

Comment: Thank you so much, well explained :)

Comment: @user2668652: On a related note, the structure that allows for this kind of coding is called an Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE). It's a way for JS developers to isolate code, preventing it from leaking into the global scope. Greg Franko has a really good write-up on how this works and why it's useful: http://gregfranko.com/blog/i-love-my-iife/

Answer (score -2):

It means the code following this statement has to be run in strict mode. This can be used to make sure no mistakes are made in the code following this.

More information about strict mode: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strict.asp

Comment: Thanks that part is clear now, I am struggling to understand the overall of the function, for ex is it similar to (function () {
  console.log(t);
})();

Comment: depends, where did you get this code?